# admob id from activity

Tags: android, admob

I have a question.

I added Admob banner to my app,

it works well.

The code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx-xxxxx" />
```

I want to change ads:adUnitId from mainactivity.

an example if a==1 ads:adUnitId = xxxxxxx else ads:adUnitId=yyyyyyy

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Edit:
androidmanifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="demo.com.bannertest">

    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView .setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat:
Required XML attribute "adUnitId" was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the AdView Pragmatically using this code.

```
    View adContainer = findViewById(R.id.adMobView);
    AdView mAdView = new AdView(context);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId(YOUR_BANNER_ID);
    ((RelativeLayout)adContainer).addView(mAdView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And use this code in your xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/adMobView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your ad's are working fine of you set the adUnitId in the xml file?

Comment: Your need to setUnitId before        
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: I have tried it but still not work. Can you try it please if you have time?

Comment: please show me the code how you change the adUnitId in your mainActivity

Comment: AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView .setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: the crash log: Required XML attribute "adUnitId" was missing

Comment: can you please edit the question and share your AndroidManifest.xml 
your xml file and your activity code related to adview

Comment: and also paste the logcat also when the app crashes